# Using the internal field separator with curl

Tags: bash, unix, ifs

When I do...

```
ls$IFS-l
```

... I get the output I expect.

When I do...

```
curl$IFShttp://www.google.com
```

... I don't.

Am I misunderstanding internal field separators? How could I run a curl command without using any space characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put the variable within curly brackets, otherwise the shell looks for a variable called "IFShttp...":

```
curl${IFS}http://www.google.com
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work: Could not resolve host: http; nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Comment: url=www.google.com;curl$IFS$url works too, if you're looking at getting rid of { and }